# Совмещение таблицы и карты

Tags: javascript, css, yandex-maps-api, google-maps

Нужно выводить сгруппированную по координатам информацию в таблице (или лучше *heatmap* из *highcharts*) на карту. То есть, у меня есть `table` или `div` с определённой шириной, высотой, координатами начала и конца, а под этим должна быть карта словно картинка с границами точно в тех же координатах. Использовать Google или Yandex — не важно. Набросок желаемого результата:

[image: Пример]

Как это можно реализовать? Как я понял, карты не предоставляют возможности задать точные края, но можно брать текущие границы карты. А зная их и размеры карты, можно позиционировать таблицу/div на карте; но это большой и некрасивый костыль, хотелось бы способ поопрятней.

Comment: Если что, использование стандартных элементов карт не вариант, т.к. нужно выводить именно прямоугольные сегменты с описанием — несколькими строками текста в таблице или всплывающим окошком в highcharts.

Comment: У Google есть механизм пользовательских наложений на карту в заданных координатах: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays?hl=ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конечном итоге, я написал библиотеку *GMapsTable* для автоматизации этой задачи. Таблица реализована как наложение поверх карты Гугл.
[Рабочий пример](https://www.aivanf.com/static/gmt/example.html), [Статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/330920/).

[image: Скриншот 1]
[image: Скриншот 2]

---

Главная цель моей библиотеки — не кластеризация данных, а их детализированное отображение на карте в виде таблицы. Если Вам нужны другие виды наложений, существуют такие решения:

- [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/cluster.html), очень мощная библиотека с массой различных видов наложений и модификаций карты.
- [LeaftLet](http://leafletjs.com/examples.html), тожее имеет разные виды наложений; главная цель этой библиотеки — удобство использования на мобильных устройствах.